# Mark the targeted todo as Done and not all the Todos list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I am trying to mark a todo done when I press the targeted one, instead when i press done all the todos are marked done.
I have no idea why this behavior is happening since i am setting the setDoneTast to true so the css class will run.

```
 import { useState } from "react";
 import "./App.scss";

 function App() {
     //Value of Input
     const [val, setVal] = useState("");
     const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
     const [doneTask, setDoneTast] = useState(false);

     const addTodos = (e) => {
       if (val == "") return;
       e.preventDefault();
       setTodos([...todos, val]);
       setVal("");
      };

      const handleDelete = (id) => {
        setTodos(todos.filter((_, key) => key !== id));
      };

    ** const handleDoneTask = (id) => {
       setDoneTast(!doneTask);
     };**

    return (
         <div className="App">
         {/** On change values*/}
           <form onSubmit={addTodos}>
            <input
              onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)}
              value={val}
              type="text"
            />
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
          </form>
          <ul>
             {todos.map((todo, key) => (
             <div className="arrange" key={key}>
                <li className={doneTask ? "doneTask" : null}>{todo}</li>
                **<a onClick={() => handleDoneTask(key)}>Done</a>**
                <a onClick={() => handleDelete(key)}>Cancel</a>
             </div>
                ))}
           </ul>
          </div>
         );
         }

      export default App;
 
   //CSS
    .doneTask {
       text-decoration: line-through!important;

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is normal react behavior.
All the todos are marked done when you press an individual one because all of your todo element check on the same state hook **doneTask** instead of theirs own 'doneTask' value.

What you want to do is to set a state array that contain for each todo element their own doneTask property. (you can put it in your **todos** hook)
And then instead of `className={doneTask ? "doneTask" : null}` you do `className={todos[i].doneTask ? "doneTask" : null}`

You are really close, you already know how to edit an array in a state hook using the Spread syntax (...) so just a few code changes and your good!

Comment: If this helped you then don't forget to mark your post as answered.
It help the other to see the more appropriate answer.

Comment: I am still trying to figure it out mate